# Why would a x86 compiled application work on 64 bit windows machine?

Tags: c#

[image: screenshot]

I installed windows 7 `64 bit` and then I installed visual studio 2015 then created C# application using windows forms and I compiled this application as `x86` (as shown in screenshot) to creat the `exe` file . After that I installed the `.exe` file on another `64 bit` windows 7 and the application worked fine!

My question is: why this `x86` complied application would work on `64 bit` machine. I read that if I compile application as `x86` it would only work on x86 machines.

Can anyone explain why it worked on 64 bit machine? thank you

Comment: 64-bit Windows comes with a 32-bit emulator. (This emulator can be disabled, but it's enabled by default.)

Comment: You can run 32bit software on a 64bit machine but not the opposite.

Comment: Why don't you [ask the manufacturer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows)?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Itanium Windows (which is 64 bit) has such an emulator.  But I doubt Kate has an Itanium.  WOW64 layer used on Windows x64 (AMD64 and EM64T machines) isn't an emulator, it's a shim wrapper with trampolines that set the correct CPU mode, and then x86 code executes directly on the CPU using support in the hardware.  But you knew that, so why call it an emulator incorrectly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

Comment: @BenVoigt You have to tailor your answer to the audience. It's clear that discussion of CPU modes would not be helpful here. Besides, there's more to simulating 32-bit Windows than changing the CPU mode. There's an entire fake file system and fake registry. I think emulation is an appropriate term.

Comment: @Raymond: Pretty sure all the documentation also calls the file system and registry magic "virtualization" and never "emulation".

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your 64bit CPU is specically designed for this as well as the operating system you're using.
In short, the OS detect that you're trying to run a x86 application and put the CPU in x86 compatibility mode before executing your application.